# Sending POST request in iframe of task Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Currently, I have Microsoft Teams bot which has an extension button that opens up an HTML page in an iframe. On the HTML page, there's a form with a submit button that submits the info the user entered. The problem I'm running into is that when the user hits the submit button it doesn't make the HTTP POST request. I've tested the iframe outside of teams and it works fine. I was wondering if this is a problem with how I have the iframe or actual HTML page setup or something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask()` function, or just trying to do the POST directly? I suspect you are doing the latter. Teams has to be in charge of the actual submit because otherwise it has no idea that the POST ever happened since it happens in an `<iframe>`.

If that's your problem, here's an example of how to do it. This is an excerpt of [the JS/Pug code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-nodejs/blob/master/src/views/customform.pug) from the sample running on Azure; I just tested it and it works fine:

```
  [...]

  function validateForm() {
    let customerInfo = {
      name: document.forms["customerForm"]["name"].value,
      email: document.forms["customerForm"]["email"].value,
      favoriteBook: document.forms["customerForm"]["favoriteBook"].value
    }
    guidRegex = /^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i;
    let password = document.getElementById("pw").value;
    if (guidRegex.test(password)) {
      microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(customerInfo, password); // hidden feature to test bogus completion appId
    }
    else {
      microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(customerInfo, "#{appId}"); //- appId is passed at render time in tabs.ts
    }
    return true;
  }

[...]

div(class='surface')
  div(class='panel')
    div(class='font-semibold font-title') Enter new customer information:
    form(method='POST' id="customerForm" action='/register' onSubmit="return validateForm()")
      div
        div.form-group(class="form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px")
        label(for='name') Name: 
        input#name.form-control.input-field(type='text', placeholder='first and last' name='name' tabindex=1 autofocus)
        div.form-group(class="form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px;")
        label(for='email') Email: 
        input#email.form-control.input-field(type='email', placeholder='name@email.com' name='email' tabindex=2)
        div.form-group(class="form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px;")
        label(for='favoriteBook') Favorite book: 
        input#favoriteBook.form-control.input-field(type='text', placeholder='title of book' name='favoriteBook' tabindex=3)
        div.form-group(class="form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px;")
        label(for='pw') Password: 
        input#pw.form-control.input-field(type='password' name='password' tabindex=4)
        div.form-group(class="form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px;")
        label(for='pw2') Confirm password: 
        input#pw2.form-control.input-field(type='password' name='confirmPassword' style="margin-bottom: 10px;" tabindex=4)
        button.btn.button-primary(type='submit' tabindex=5) Sign up
```

Comment: Thank you that is what fixed it. Does displaying the app-id in the JavaScript pose any serious security risks?

Comment: Good question - no, app IDs are not secret.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely relates to the list of Valid Domains in your app manifest file. Are you using App Studio? If so, on the "Domains and Permissions" section you need to have the POST endpoint listed as a valid domain (just the domain part, not the full url).

If you're not using App Studio, or just want more reference, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#validdomains)

Comment: I just checked and the domain is in validDomains, the POST is being sent to the same path as the GET request to pull up the HTML.

Comment: ok. Have you tried running Teams in the browser instead of the desktop client? That way you can track this using regular F12 browser tools, that might help show the error